# python3 pySerial TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes:

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, pyserial

In Python 3 I imported the pySerial library so I could communicate with my Arduino Uno by serial commands.
It worked very well in Python 2.7 but in Python 3 I keep running into a error it says this

> ***TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: 'allon'***

In Python 2.7 the only thing I did differently is use `raw_input` but I don't know what is happening in Python 3. Here is my code

```
import serial, time
import tkinter
import os

def serialcmdw():
    os.system('clear')
    serialcmd = input("serial command: ")
    ser.write (serialcmd)

serialcmdw()

ser = serial.Serial()
os.system('clear')
ser.port = "/dev/cu.usbmodem4321"
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.open()
time.sleep(1)
serialcmdw()
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Encode your data which you are writing to serial,in your case  "serialcmd" to bytes.try the following :

```
ser.write(serialcmd.encode())
```

Answer (score 27):

i found same you problem for learn "Arduino Python Serial" 
  **You can do another way this:**

```
ser.write(str.encode('allon'))
```

Answer (score 7):

If we have the string itself and not in a variable, we can do like this:

```py
    ser.write(b'\x0101')
```

This will convert the string to `bytes` type