# Arduino single LED TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror

I have ArduinoUNO, I use Python3. I want to make a single LED ON and OFF on command.  But I get errors.

ON
TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: 'H'
OFF
TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: 'L'

What I am doing wrong?
Here's my code:

```
import serial
import time


arduino = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600)

def onOffFunction():
    command = input("Type in something (on/off/bye): ");
    if command == "on":
         print ("The LED is ON")
         time.sleep(1)
         arduino.write('H')
         onOffFunction()
    elif command == "off":
        print ("The LED is OFF")
        time.sleep(1)
        arduino.write('L')
        onOffFunction()
    elif command == "bye":
        print ("Bye Bye!")
        time.sleep(1)
        arduino.close()
    else:
        print ("Sorry.. Try typing something else.")
        onOffFunction()

time.sleep(2)

onOffFunction()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python3 pySerial TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642855/python3-pyserial-typeerror-unicode-strings-are-not-supported-please-encode-to)

Answer (score 1):

An explanation can be found [here](https://playground.arduino.cc/interfacing/python):

> Writing data to Arduino is easy too (the following applies to Python
>   2.x):
>
> > import serial # if you have not already done so
> >
> > ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial', 9600)
> >
> > ser.write('5')
>
> In Python 3.x the strings are Unicode by default. When sending data to
>   Arduino, they have to be converted to bytes. This can be done by
>   prefixing the string with b:
>
> > ser.write(b'5') # prefix b is required for Python 3.x, optional for Python 2.x

Comment: The code now is errorless, yet the LED blinks and does not correspond to my ON/OFF code functions. I have no idea what might be wrong. :/

Comment: EDIT:I found out that whatever code I make on Arduino IDE it stucks and does not respond to any python code.

Comment: @simeon9446 What you are asking is not a specific question. You need someone to help you troubleshoot the setup. Stackoverflow is not intended for such things, it is a strictly Q/A site. Maybe try to ask on official Arduino forum? I am sure many people there would be happy to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Adding prefix b' (byte conversion) has helped to make code errorless, however, ArduinoUNO does not respond to Python3 but responds to ArduinoIDE.