# How do I Input a time schedule where in it will open and close based on given time using Arduino and Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, arduino-uno

Good day!

I'm currently undergoing to a project where in my goal is that to create a time-based program that can open a light and closed it according to the inputted time of the user and now I'm currently having a problem to Tkinter I can set a time but whenever i set a time the commands get an error and it won't turn on according to the given time I do know about about the logic of my program I just can't figure out what command do I use to turn the lights on according to specified time given.

I do appreciate the effort of answering in my question.

My code is given Below:

ARDUINO:

```
#include <DS3231.h>

int Relay = 4;
DS3231 rtc (SDA, SCL);
Time t;

const int OnHour = 10;
const int OnMin = 47;
const int OFFHour = 10;
const int OFFMin = 48;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  rtc.begin();
  pinMode(Relay, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);

}

void loop() {
t = rtc.getTime();
  Serial.print(t.hour);
  Serial.print(" hour(s), ");
  Serial.print(t.min);
  Serial.print(" minute(s) ");
  Serial.println(" ");
  delay (1000);

 if (t.hour == OnHour && t.min == OnMin) {

  digitalWrite(Relay,HIGH);
  Serial.println("LIGHT ON");
 }
 else if (t.hour == OFFHour && t.min == OFFMin) {
  digitalWrite(Relay,LOW);
  Serial.println("LIGHT OFF");
 }
}
```

TKINTER PYTHON:

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
import time
import time as tm
import random
import os
import sys
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
import time as tm
import serial
from serial import Serial
import tkinter

ser1 = serial.Serial('COM6', 115200)


def led_off():
    ser1.write('0')


def led_on():
    ser1.write('1')


def save_info():
    onhour_info = onHour.get()
    onmin_info = onMin.get()
    offhour_info = offHour.get()
    offmin_info = offMin.get()
    x = datetime.datetime.now()

    print("Congratulations! You just set an Starting Time of", onhour_info, ":", onmin_info)
    print("Congratulations! You just set an Ending Time of", offhour_info, ":", offmin_info)

    if onhour_info == x.strftime('%H') and onmin_info == x.strftime('%M'):
        led_on()

    elif offhour_info == x.strftime('%H') and offmin_info == x.strftime('%M'):
        led_off()


window = Tk()
window.geometry("800x400")
window.title("Automated Light Integrated System")

label1 = Label(window, text="Welcome User!", font=("arial", 24, "bold"), relief="solid").place(x=300, y=10)
label2 = Label(window, text=time.strftime('%H:%M %p'), font=("arial", 10), relief="solid").place(x=700, y=10)

label3 = Label(window, text="Please Indicate your Starting Time", font=("arial", 12)).place(x=30, y=90)
onHour = StringVar()
label4 = Label(window, text="Hour(s) ", font=("arial", 10)).place(x=10, y=120)
hour_entry = Entry(textvariable=onHour, width="5").place(x=60, y=121)

onMin = StringVar()
label5 = Label(window, text="Minute(s) ", font=("arial", 10)).place(x=90, y=120)
min_entry = Entry(textvariable=onMin, width="5").place(x=150, y=120)

register1 = Button(window, text="Set Time", width="20", height="2", command=led_on).place(x=300, y=120)

label6 = Label(window, text="Please Indicate your Ending Time: ", font=("arial", 12)).place(x=500, y=90)
offHour = StringVar()
label7 = Label(window, text="Hour(s) ", font=("arial", 10)).place(x=500, y=120)
hour_entry = Entry(textvariable=offHour, width="5").place(x=550, y=121)

offMin = StringVar()
label8 = Label(window, text="Minute(s) ", font=("arial", 10)).place(x=570, y=120)
min_entry = Entry(textvariable=offMin, width="5").place(x=630, y=120)


window.mainloop()
```

THIS IS THE INTERFACED OF MY PROGRAM:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Dp6x.jpg)

THIS IS THE ERROR IM GETTING:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File

```
"C:\Users\aadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Ramos/Documents/Project/ALIS/Alis Program.py", line 22, in led_on
    ser1.write('1')
  File "C:\Users\Ramos\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 308, in write
    data = to_bytes(data)
  File "C:\Users\Ramos\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 63, in to_bytes
    raise TypeError('unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: {!r}'.format(seq))
TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '1'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python3 pySerial TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642855/python3-pyserial-typeerror-unicode-strings-are-not-supported-please-encode-to)

Comment: `ser1.write('1')` is invalid since you are writing a string to the serial, you could do `ser1.write(b'1')` which would send a bytes literal, however this would be the bytes representing '1' as character, not necessarily as a high/low state as I believe you are intending it

Comment: @HymnsForDisco yes I'm intending to make the high/ow state that could turn the lights on and off

Comment: @Prudhvi I'll examine that link later thank you!

Comment: Ok.  From my understanding, your arduino program needs to be updated as it never reads from the serial connection. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/read/  Try setting up a serial read and print statement in your arduino program to confirm if you can get a byte message through with ser1.write(b'A'), or any character

Comment: ohh okay so I need to make an connection between my serial connection to tkinter? where in if I inputted an time in the tkinter the serial read in the arduino will read the specified time I given in the tkinter is that right?

Comment: Yes, the code that you have posted originally simply has 2 separate programs which establish a serial connection with each other, but both are only writing and not reading so no communication is actually happening.  You've said that you want to take an inputted time (from tkinter), and use it to control a light (which is attached to the arduino), therefore the arduino must be reading what the serial is saying or that information will never be transferred from one program to the other.  In order to do this though you will have to encode the values to bytes and then decode to numbers on arduino

Comment: Just have an update! my program is now currently working thanks for the both of you! but there is a bit of a problem but I think I can top it now!