# TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes:

Tags: python

Context : I am trying to make the servo follow my face why is it showing this error?

[ERROR HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5wtD.png)

Comment: what is your data, and please paste some code in question

Comment: Have you considered doing as the error suggests very explicitly, and `encode()` your strings to bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't output strings over a serial interface since serial interfaces accept bytes, not text.

Do

```
arduino.write(data.encode('ascii'))
```

to encode your command string into ASCII bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the string to bytes. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642855/python3-pyserial-typeerror-unicode-strings-are-not-supported-please-encode-to). It would be great if you could paste your code here and give more details.